# How to draw an arc beetween two fractions?

Tags: arrows, fractions

I want to mark a fraction, which I shorten, with an arc. Haver anybody an idea how to start?
I wish that it looks like the text in the picture. Is there a way to do it?

[image: The result should look like that.]

Comment: Thank you. I hoped that there is an easier way to do it, but at least it seems to work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {\bfseries \Huge $\frac{8}{12}$ \;=\; $\frac{2}{3}$};
        \draw[->,line width=2pt] (-.8,1) arc (120:60:2) node[pos=.5,above] () {\bfseries \huge :4};
        \draw[->,line width=2pt] (-.8,-1) arc (-120:-60:2) node[pos=.5,below] () {\bfseries \huge :4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**ADD**: But perhaps is better this picture:

[image]

You need to change the last line of code:

```
\draw[<-,line width=2pt] (-.8,-1) arc (-120:-60:2) node[pos=.5,below] () {\bfseries \huge $\times$4};
```

**EDIT**: Surely in text mode is more difficult and I dont know how to make this. With `tikz` You can also have more examples on the same line, like this:

[image]

The above picture is done by this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {\bfseries \Huge $\frac{8}{12}$ \;=\; $\frac{2}{3}$};
        \draw[->,line width=2pt] (-.8,1) arc (120:60:2) node[pos=.5,above] () {\bfseries \huge :4};
        \draw[<-,line width=2pt] (-.8,-1) arc (-120:-60:2) node[pos=.5,below] () {\bfseries \huge $\times$4};
    \end{tikzpicture}\qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {\bfseries \Huge $\frac{12}{16}$ \;=\; $\frac{3}{4}$};
        \draw[->,line width=2pt] (-.8,1) arc (120:60:2) node[pos=.5,above] () {\bfseries \huge :4};
        \draw[<-,line width=2pt] (-.8,-1) arc (-120:-60:2) node[pos=.5,below] () {\bfseries \huge $\times$4};
    \end{tikzpicture}\qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {\bfseries \Huge $\frac{9}{24}$ \;=\; $\frac{3}{8}$};
        \draw[->,line width=2pt] (-.8,1) arc (120:60:2) node[pos=.5,above] () {\bfseries \huge :3};
        \draw[<-,line width=2pt] (-.8,-1) arc (-120:-60:2) node[pos=.5,below] () {\bfseries \huge $\times$3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**LAST UPDATE**: In fact, if You want to make reduction for a lot of fraction, You can define a new command `eReduce` with 5 parameters and call this command for each fraction to reduce. The complete code with four fractions to reduce:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\newcommand*{\eReduce}[5]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {\bfseries \Huge $\frac{#1}{#2}$ \;=\; $\frac{#3}{#4}$};
        \draw[->,line width=2pt] (-.8,1) arc (120:60:2) node[pos=.5,above] () {\bfseries \huge :#5};
        \draw[<-,line width=2pt] (-.8,-1) arc (-120:-60:2) node[pos=.5,below] () {\bfseries \huge $\times$#5};
        \draw[line width=2pt] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \eReduce{8}{12}{2}{3}{4}\qquad
    \eReduce{12}{16}{3}{4}{4}\qquad
    \eReduce{9}{24}{3}{8}{3}\qquad
    \eReduce{75}{125}{3}{5}{25}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that looks really nice. But there is no way to do it without tikz? Just with simple text?

Comment: @montarenbici See EDIT, in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that looks really nice. But I guess it is kind of difficult to add three TikZ next to each other? Especially if you want to adapt a fraction? Like the numerator gets bigger, than everything will be shifted to right?

Comment: @montarenbici See my last edit to view the code of the last picture.